# Can I tether Internet from one android device to another android device using USB?

Tags: usb, internet, tethering, remix-os

I have a [Jide Remix Mini](http://www.jide.com/mini) and it is a pain in the neck when it comes to Wifi. It seems as if it steals the I.P. Address of another device on the router, sucks up all the bandwidth, and then still can't get fast speeds. Of course, all the other devices on the router start having issues as well.

I also have an android phone, and I LOVE IT. I have tethered my computer to it to give it Wifi when the wifi card quit, and it's done a fine job.

So now I had an idea. Would it be possible to tether my phone (android) to my Remix Mini (also android)? I want to give the Remix mini Internet WITHOUT connecting it directly to the router via it's Wifi card. I tried doing it via Bluetooth, but I only got speeds of .2 megabits/second (our router sends about 12 megabits/second). So I tried plugging in my phone to the Remix's USB port and then in settings checked "USB Tethering". The Remix seems to not recognize the device as a source of Internet.

Is there something I'm missing? How can I fix this problem, or can it be fixed at all? I have other devices that I am willing to use listed below. Thanks!

My usable devices:
iPad Mini 2, iOS 9.3, Jailbroken
Polaroid A4 Phone, Android 4.4, Rooted
Remix Mini, Android 5.1 Base with Remix OS 2.1 interface, NOT rooted
Computer, Ubuntu 16.04, missing a Wifi adapter (need to connect via phone tethering)

Comment: I was also look for this question to answer in prime and Phoenix os we can just turn on USB tethering at boot logo since after boot if we turn on they won detect in remix it does work in either way